# sort csv file and delete older rows specified to a column

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv as below in the file "script.csv"

```
author,Revision,Path   
abc,9947,spc.sql  
xyz,9806,lmn.sql  
xyz,9810,lmn.sql  
xyz,9897,file.sql  
def,9811,test1.rdl  
def,9813,test1.rdl
```

I am trying to delete a row with duplicate and has a older revision. the new output in the file "script.csv" should look like this below .

```
author,Revision,Path   
abc,9947,spc.sql  
xyz,9810,lmn.sql  
xyz,9897,file.sql  
def,9813,test1.rdl
```

I have tried below code and struck

```
$inputFile = 'D:\script.csv'
$inputCsv = Import-Csv $inputFile | Sort-Object * -Unique
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `Sort-Object` combined with `Group-Object`

```
$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv "author,Revision,Path
abc,9947,spc.sql
xyz,9806,lmn.sql
xyz,9810,lmn.sql
xyz,9897,file.sql
def,9811,test1.rdl
def,9813,test1.rdl"

$csv | Sort-Object -Property author,Path,Revision -Descending | Group-Object author,Path | foreach {
    $_.Group[0]
}
```

Output:

```
author Revision Path     
------ -------- ----     
xyz    9810     lmn.sql  
xyz    9897     file.sql 
def    9813     test1.rdl
abc    9947     spc.sql
```

Comment: Thanks! BUt I am very new to powershell and If the above content is in file "script.csv", then where do i mention the file name ? I tried this but no luck --$input = "script.csv" ConvertFrom-Csv -InputObject $input -Header "author,Revision,Path"

Comment: Its was my bad that i did not put in the requirements properly , i have corrected now though.

Comment: @script0207 Use `$csv = import-csv $input -Delimiter ','`

Comment: @script0207: The problem is that `$input` is a reserved variable; use a different variable name.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an accepted answer.  I thought I'd add this one to clear up a few minor points.

**The Script:**

```
Import-csv script.csv |
    Sort -desc author,path,revision |
    Group-Object author,path |
    foreach {$_.Group | Select -first 1 } |
    Export-csv newscript.csv -notype
```

**Input File:**

```
author,Revision,Path
abc,9947,spc.sql
xyz,9806,lmn.sql
xyz,9810,lmn.sql
xyz,9897,file.sql
def,9811,test1.rdl
def,9813,test1.rdl
```

**Output File:**

```
"author","Revision","Path"
"xyz","9810","lmn.sql"
"xyz","9897","file.sql"
"def","9813","test1.rdl"
"abc","9947","spc.sql"
```

**Notes:**

I changed the specs a little to write the output to a different file than the input.  That's just so that, if the script does something unfortunate,  you still have the input 
file available.  That's my habit.  You can change it for the way you do things.

For reasons I can't figure out,  I couldn't make this work from the csv file you posted.
I had to type the csv file in by hand to make it work.

The -notype in the Export-csv is to prevent an extra line in the output file.

What are those quote marks in the output file?  Well, Export-csv likes to do things by the book, and surrounds character strings with double quote marks.  There may be a way to disable that.  It may not do you any harm, if your other software reacts appropriately to quote marks in csv files.

Yes, but why is Revision surrounded by quotes, if it's a number?  Well,  Import-csv didn't recognize it as a number,  and treated the values of Revision as strings.  And there's a hidden problem here, which follows.

Which comes first,  "9999" or "10000".  If you treat them numerically,  9999 comes first.  But if you treat them as character strings, and sort alphabetically,  "10000" comes before "9999".  This problem never surfaced because in your test data, all the Revisions had the same number of digits.  But that probably won't be true in the real world.  You may have to figure out how to get Import-csv to treat revision as a number, or you may have to recast the Revisions as numbers before you sort.